# Why are the hidden files/directories seen in Terminal color settings?

Tags: macos, terminal

When I tried to set my Terminal color by importing a color scheme stored in `~/Dropbox/.personal/myColor.Terminal`, it didn't display the hidden directories, including `~/Dropbox/.personal` (and other files and directories I store to my Dropbox root, such as `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc`).

Why does this not display it? I always show those hidden directories by setting the `AppleShowAllFiles` property in `com.apple.finder` to 1.

It's just the Terminal color setting import pane that I recognize to NOT be displayed - in other words, I've seen those hidden files everywhere on my daily use.

I can just move the color scheme file temporarily to import it on my Terminal - just want to know why such incongruity occurs.

I use the latest version of OS X Mavericks. Any feedbacks would be appreciated.

#### Update

I got that it's not only Terminal, but it can be applied to other applications as well, on which when you do `Open Files` or `Import` or similar operations, most applications don't display those hidden files. As far as I know, only MacVim has a checkbox option to open those hidden files.

Comment: Can you see the files in Terminal before you apply the colour scheme?

Comment: What do you mean in "see files in Terminal"? If you mean `com.apple.Terminal.plist`, then I can see the file's contents by issuing `plutil -convert xml1 -o - com.apple.Terminal.plist`.

Comment: Does ls show the files before you import the colour scheme

Comment: Yes, `ls` works properly. And I just noticed that it's not the issue on Terminal - check out my comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: You should add more information into the question if relevant - Comments should be treated as if they might be deleted in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this likely has to do with how terminals work. In bash they are hidden by most aliases of `ls`.

Try `ls -a` or `\ls -a` if that isn't working. This is to show all files and escape an alias you might have.

Put simply, the terminal doesn't care about finder preferences because it *isn't* finder.

If not, then perhaps terminal simply doesn't respect the finder settings.

Comment: `ls -a` (or more simply, just `ls`) properly lists all files including those hidden ones. But I just noticed that it's not only Terminal - most applications don't display those hidden files on the `Open Files` or `Import` or similar dialog. I didn't recognize it... MacVim has an checkbox option to show them, though.